# Sci-Fi book with a young Latin woman saved from assault by an alien military officer

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

It's a book in which the first scene involves a very young Latin woman walking home, and she thinks she sees a man appear almost from nowhere on a street.

Shortly after, she is about to be molested by a gang member but is saved by a mysterious stranger, who is an alien military officer.

Comment: Hi there! :) this is a bit light at the moment, could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, when did you read that? Was it in English, was it a translation? Do you remember what the cover looked like? Was it part of a series or a standalone book? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: Latin as in Latin American or Latin as in Roman?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [*Primary Inversion*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/365672.Primary_Inversion), by Catherine Asaro. I think there was something about the alien race being related to Incan or Mayan people. It is the first book in the [*Saga of the Skolian Empire*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40379-saga-of-the-skolian-empire) series.

> The Skolian Empire rules a third of the civilized galaxy through its mastery of faster-than-light communication. But war with the rival empire of the Traders seems imminent, a war that can only lead to slavery for the Skolians or the destruction of both sides. Destructive skirmishes have already occurred. A desperate attempt must be made to avert total disaster.

---

The plot elements are most likely from the second written novel in the series, [*Catch the Lightning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_the_Lightning):

> The first half of Catch the Lightning takes place in an alternate Los Angeles on Earth in a time similar to the late 20th century. The main character is Tina Pulivok, a seventeen-year-old Maya girl living in East L.A. She has relocated to Los Angeles and is living on her own while she works as a waitress. The hero, Althor Selei, a cybernetically enhanced Jag fighter pilot, is thrown into the alternate universe when his star fighter malfunctions. Tina meets Althor late at night when she is returning home from work, and he is trying to figure out why he ended up on a planet that bears little resemblance to the Earth he expected. After Althor helps Tina escape an incident of gang violence, the two become fugitives.

Comment: Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9445/58193) to [edit] this answer a bit? Why is this correct? How does it match the OP's description?